# Display:inline-block not working on safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I've stucked with my friends website on a menu issue. The URL of the website is:
colorfil.webd.pl/sandbox/sylwia/

Please take a look on the menu (main navigation + top right menu + filers menu). On all modern browsers: chrome, FF, opera menu looks good. On Safari it sucks. I use this simple css (for main nav):

```
    #header-container li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 1em;
}
```

Issue - menu is being extended into total page width (so the gaps between menu items are HUGE).

Can you advice me something on that?

Comment: Can you maybe take a screenshot of the issue? I used safari without any trouble.

Comment: sure. It's a matter of margin issues. Take a look (top version is from safari, bottom from chrome): http://imgur.com/a/AecTG

Comment: Remove the min-width and the floating from the link (ul li a). It's causing the huge gaps.

Comment: I've tested here and works fine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Debugging

If something like this happens to you in the future you need to debug it.

All modern browsers feature in-built Web Inspectors/Developer Tools (and if they're not good enough for you - you can always grab [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/firebug/)).

If website looks different in X browsers all you need to do is to inspect the different-looking elements and then see what CSS rules are being applied to them. The differences are almost always related to different rules being applied. If you can't track existing rules in your CSS files they're most likely being added with JavaScript.

I've recorded a quick gif for your case, notice **everything is fine after you remove floats and min-widths from your links** (as previously stated by Imube). You don't actually need floats there, as `inline-block` will work just fine. I'd generally recommend avoiding floats wherever possible.

### Opera vs Safari - tracking your problem using Dev Tools

[image: Opera vs Safari Dev Tools]

Uncompressed: https://gifyu.com/images/debug47afb.gif

### Why it was not working

Looks like Safari <s>interprets</s> ignores `min-width: auto` in comparison other browsers (by the way what is `auto` supposed to mean in this case?).

Here's a demo that uses `min-width` of `150px` for `inline-block` link and then overwrites it with `auto`. It works fine in other browsers, but in Safari the links are still `150px` wide.

It's really easy to track down using dev tools:

**Opera:**

[image: Opera]

**Safari:**

[image: Safari]

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9mq75wgp/)

### Learn more

Read more about [dev tools for Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools), [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) and in [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/).

Comment: I like how this answer doesn't event mention IE