# Horizontally align options in select?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-select

I am working on styling an option tag for a project I am working on but I am unable to figure out if it is even possible to horizontally align the option tags in my select box.

This is what I currently have style wise:

```css
*:focus {
    outline: none;
}

select {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  padding:10px;
  margin:-5px -20px -5px -5px;
}

#drink-holder {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="drink-holder">
  <select size="6">
      <option selected>Water</option>
      <option>Apple Juice</option>
      <option>Orange Juice</option>
      <option>Milk</option>
      <option>Coffee</option>
      <option>Sports Drink</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I do have jQuery in my app but I would prefer a css only option also cross compatibility is not a problem sense this project will be packaged in webkit.

If you do not understand what I want it is simply like this:

Water Apple Juice Orange Juice ...

Thanks!

Edit: For people confused on the cross-comparability part I meant that this would be packaged in webkit to make an iOS app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply need to use `display:inline-block;` with the `select` options:

```
#drink-holder select option {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

**Demo:**

```css
*:focus {
    outline: none;
}

select {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  padding:10px;
  margin:-5px -20px -5px -5px;
}

#drink-holder select option {
  display:inline-block;
}

#drink-holder {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="drink-holder">
  <select size="6">
      <option selected>Water</option>
      <option>Apple Juice</option>
      <option>Orange Juice</option>
      <option>Milk</option>
      <option>Coffee</option>
      <option>Sports Drink</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: the result is looking the same on safari.

Comment: I haven't tested that in safari as it works in Chrome and FF, but Ithought you said *cross compatibility is not a problem*?!

Comment: I only need it running on safari sense this will be packaged in a webkit iOS app

Comment: But you can try to use `display:inline-block !important;.

Comment: Gotcha I will try it

Comment: Same thing nothing changed but thanks for the quick response

Comment: @arodebaugh Please try to debug the code in your browser following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955362/displayinline-block-not-working-on-safari) and see what css rules are being ignored?

Comment: Thanks doing that now

Comment: I am sorry this is not working for me at all and I followed the debugging stuff but there seemed to be no issues... gonna either wait for another answer or play around to try to make your answer work for me