# HTML form with horizontally expanded select options

Tags: html, css, forms

I would like to write an HTML form with a short select field with the following features:

- All options are visible. That can be easily achieved with "size" = number of items.
- Those items should be displayed explicitly next to the label (on the right), as if they were switchable buttons.

If the code is something like this...

```html
    <div class="row">
        <label for="myvar">Chose an option:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="myvar" name="myvar" size="5">
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="0" class="text-primary">Yes</option>
            <option value="1" class="text-warning">No</option>
            <option value="2" class="text-mutted">Sometimes</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

I would like to have something like:

Chose an option: `Yes` `No` `Sometimes`

Basically, having the select options expanded horizontally to the right and visible.

Comment: The first `<option>` tag is not closed

Comment: why don't use a list of radioboxes instead of a select? the controls can be easily hidden

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontally align options in select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45327723/horizontally-align-options-in-select)

Comment: @fcalderan: That's also a good idea...

Comment: @JulenLarruceaI have prepared a demo. I could post it as an answer if you are interested.

Comment: @fcalderan: Sure :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a select I would suggest to use a list of radioboxes
e.g.

```css
ul {
  display         : flex;
  justify-content : center;
  margin          : 50px auto;
  font            : 1.5rem Arial;
  color           : #335;
  list-style      : none;
  padding         : 0;
}

li:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}

input {
  position : absolute;
  clip     : rect(0 0 0 0);
  width    : 1px;
  height   : 1px;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .3em .75em;
  background: #9bc;
  color: #556; 
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .5s 0s;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

:checked +  label {
  background: #556;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: default;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff, 0 0 0 4px #556;
}
```

```html
<ul>
     <li>
       <input type="radio" name="choice" value="0" id="choice--yes"/>
       <label for="choice--yes">Yes</label>
     </li>
     <li>
       <input type="radio" name="choice" value="1" id="choice--no"/>
       <label for="choice--no">No</label>
     </li>
     <li>
       <input type="radio" name="choice" value="2" id="choice--sometimes"/>
       <label for="choice--sometimes">Sometimes</label>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can reach this by setting select display as **table-row** and option as **table-cell**. The -webkit-appearance property is used to display an element using a platform-native styling based on the users' operating system's, so we need to disable it and our select become more stylable.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

select {
  display: table-row;
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  table-layout: unset;
  height: 14px;
}

select option {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <label for="myvar">Chose an option:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="myvar" name="myvar" size="5">
            <option value="0" class="text-primary">Yes</option>
            <option value="1" class="text-warning">No</option>
            <option value="2" class="text-mutted">Sometimes</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Perhaps some context about why this fixes the problem would be helpful?

Comment: There is a typo, it is `option` not `options`

Comment: @Satif Please edit your answer and explain how your code solves the OP's problem.  A link in the comments to someone else's answer is not the right way to do that.