# my sub-menu is not showing in safari but it's does in chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I was making my sub-menu bar for [my site](http://underkoen.nl).
It works fine for chrome and firefox but on safari it's is there because, I can click on the sub-menu items but there are not visible. I had before the similar problem on chrome when there were multiple sub-menu's. I fixed it by making it fixed and set the top and left.

html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="material/material.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="menu/menu.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="sidebar/sidebar.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="background/background.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <script src="material/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="material/material.min.js"></script>
        <script src="background/background.js"></script>
        <script src="sidebar/sidebar.js"></script>
        <script src="menu/menu.js"></script>
        <script src="menu/telMenu.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class="bg-wrapper">
            <span class="bg"></span>
            <span class="bg"></span>
            <span class="bg"></span>
            <span class="bg"></span>
            <span class="bg"></span>
        </span>
        <div class="top">
            <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header mdl-layout--fixed-tabs">
                <header class="mdl-layout__header">
                    <div role="button" tabindex="0" class="mdl-layout__drawer-button" onclick="showSidebar()">
                        <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
                        <span class="mdl-layout-title">UnderKoen.nl</span>
                    </div>
                </header>
                <div class="sidebar">
                    <span class="mdl-layout-title">Menu</span>
                    <i class="material-icons closeButton" onclick="hideSidebar()">clear</i>
                    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
                        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Home</a>
                        <a class="mdl-navigation__link external_link" href="https://school.underkoen.nl" target="_blank">
                            School
                        </a>
                        <a class="mdl-navigation__link external_link" href="https://github.com/UnderKoen" target="_blank">
                            Github
                        </a>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-layout__header-row"></div>
            <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#.about">About</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#.projects">Projects</a>
                    <div class="drp-down">
                        <div class="menu">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." class="search"><div class="sub-menu">
                                <a>Java</a>
                                <div class="menu">
                                    <a href="#.rubik">Rubik's Cube</a>
                                    <a href="#.monopoly">Monopoly</a>
                                    <a href="#.discordbot">Discord Bot</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sub-menu">
                                <a>Python</a>
                                <div class="menu">
                                    <a href="#.snake">Snake</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <main>
            <div class="fancy"></div>
            <div class="top2"></div>
            <div class="mdl-grid mdl-layout__content mainindex">
                <div class="mdl-card mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col index" id="about">
                    <span class="title">About</span>
                    <span class="content">

                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-card mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col index" id="projects">
                    <span class="title">Projects</span>
                    <span class="content">
                        <div class="mdl-card mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col subindex" id="snake">
                            <span class="title">Snake</span>
                            <span class="content">
                                <par>
                                    Dit was het eerst spel wat ik echt heb gemaakt. Het is gemaakt in Python, ben begonnen met het maken van Snake in 2013. Het is gemaakt met PyGame. Heb helaas geen screenshot van het spel meer maar het was ong het standaart Snake spel.
                                </par>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mdl-card mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col subindex" id="rubik">
                            <span class="title">Rubik's Cube</span>
                            <span class="content">
                                <par>Dit was mijn tweede spel wat ik heb gemaakt. Het was mijn eerst spel wat ik had gemaakt in Java, ik was begonnen met het maken van de Rubik's Cube in de vakantie in 2016. Het is gemaakt met behulp van JavaFx dit is een interface libarie voor Java. In het spel is een grote fout wat komt door een niet handige manier van id's opslaan. tijdens het maken van dit spel heb ik mijn vaardig heden met java enorm vergroot. Hier is de code van het programma: <a href="https://github.com/UnderKoen/Rubik-s-Cube">Github</a></par>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mdl-card mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col subindex" id="monopoly">
                            <span class="title">Monopoly</span>
                            <span class="content">
                                <par>Dit was mijn eerste spel wat multiplayer zou hebben. Het spel heb ik gemaakt in Java, in het begin van het project werkte ik samen met iemand maar hij had na paar dagen geen zin er om verder te werken dus toen stond ik er alleen voor. Ik had de server kant uiteindelijk af en was bezig met de client. helaas heb ik het spel niet afgemaakt omdat ik geen insperatie had om het spel af te maken. ik denk als me klasgenoot nog hielp dat het ondertussen speelbaar was. De code van het programma staat wel nog online: <a href="https://github.com/UnderKoen/Monopoly">Github</a></par>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mdl-card mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col subindex" id="discordbot">
                            <span class="title">Discord Bot</span>
                            <span class="content">
                                <par>Dit was een bot die ik had gemaakt voor iemand en nog steeds onderhou. Ik heb deze Bot 4,5 keer geschreven wegens updates en ander bullshit ik begon het te maken in C# Discord.net alleen deze werdt na een tijdje niet meer gesupport dus moest over stappen naar de nieuwe update Discord.net 1.0 hier had ik de bot wel af maar hij crashde steeds dus dacht ik dat ik hem maar opnieuw zou gaan schrijven. dit ging helaas niet heet succesvol en ik stapte halvewegen om naar een Java Libarie JDA hier had ik eerst een hele simple versie geschreven om hem online te hebben en later heb ik het vanaf de handlers af zelf gemaakt. De code van de <a href="https://github.com/UnderKoen/UnderBotCSharp">Dicord.net 1.0 bot</a> en de code van de <a href="https://github.com/UnderKoen/UnderBot">JDA bot</a></par>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
window.setTimeout(atStart, 1);
window.setTimeout(update, 100);

function update() {
    $("ul li .drp-down .menu").css("max-height", ($("ul li .drp-down .menu a").first().outerHeight() + 24) * 4);
    var lis = $("#myTopnav").find("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
        var obj = $(lis[i]);
        if (obj.hasClass("active")) {
            obj.removeClass("active");
        }
        var click = obj.find("a");
        for (var p = 0; p < click.length; p++) {
            var a = $(click[p]);
            if (document.URL == a.prop("href")) {
                obj.addClass("active");
                if (a.attr('href').includes("#.")) {
                    if (hasParentsClass(a,"drp-down")) {
                        sort($(click[0]).attr('href').substring(2), a.attr('href').substring(2));
                        select($(click[0]).attr('href').substring(2));
                    } else {
                        deSort(a.attr('href').substring(2))
                        select(a.attr('href').substring(2));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var lis1 = document.getElementsByClassName("top");
    var lis2 = document.getElementsByClassName("top2");
    var lis3 = document.getElementsByClassName("fancy");
    lis2[0].style.minHeight = (lis1[0].clientHeight + 40);
    lis3[0].style.minHeight = (lis1[0].clientHeight + 60);

    window.setTimeout(ehmmm, 670);
}   

function ehmmm() {
    $(".ink").remove();
}

function atStart(){
    update();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10) { //use `this`, not `document`
            $('.topnav').css({
                'display': 'none'
            });
        } else {
            $('.topnav').css({
                'display': 'inherit'
            });
        }
    });

    var parent, ink, d, x, y;
    $("ul li a").click(function(e){
        $(".ink").remove();
        parent = $(this).parent();
        if ($(this).parents().filter("div.drp-down").length == 0) {
            if(parent.find(".ink").length == 0)
                parent.prepend("<span class='ink'></span>");

            ink = parent.find(".ink");
            ink.removeClass("animate");

            if(!ink.height() && !ink.width())
            {
                d = Math.max(parent.outerWidth(), parent.outerHeight());
                ink.css({height: d, width: d});
            }
            x = e.pageX - parent.offset().left - ink.width()/2;
            y = e.pageY - parent.offset().top - ink.height()/2;

            ink.css({top: y+'px', left: x+'px'}).addClass("animate");
        }
    })

    $("ul li a").click(function(e){
        setTimeout(update, 10);
    });

    $("ul li .drp-down .search").keyup(function(e){
        var input = $(e.currentTarget);
        var filter = input.val().toUpperCase();
        var div = input.parent();
        var a = div.find("a");
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            var obj = a[i];
            if (obj.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                obj.style.display = "";

                if (hasParentsClass(obj, "menu")) {
                    var parents = $(obj).parents(".menu");
                    for (var i2 = 0; i2 < parents.length; i2++) {
                        parents.get(i2).parentElement.firstElementChild.style.display = "";
                        a.remove(parents.get(i2).parentElement.firstElementChild);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                obj.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    });

    $('ul li .drp-down .menu').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
        var prevend = false;
        if ($(e.target).parent().hasClass("menu")) {
            if (e.delegateTarget.parentElement.className != "sub-menu" && e.delegateTarget.parentElement.className != "drp-down" ||
                e.target.parentElement != e.currentTarget) {
                prevend = true;    
            }
        }
        if (!prevend) {
            var scrollTo = null;
            if (e.type == 'mousewheel') {
                scrollTo = (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta * -1);
            }
            else if (e.type == 'DOMMouseScroll') {
                scrollTo = 40 * e.originalEvent.detail;
            }

            if (scrollTo) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).scrollTop(scrollTo + $(this).scrollTop());
            }
        }
    });

    $("ul li .drp-down .menu .sub-menu").hover(function(e) {
        var obj = $(e.currentTarget);
        var obj2 = $(obj.find(".menu").get(0));
        var pos = $(obj.find("a").get(0));

        obj2.css("top", pos.offset().top);
        obj2.css("left", pos.offset().left + obj.width());
    });
}
```

css:

```
.drop {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}

ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #00796B;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 60px;
    margin-left: 60px;
}

ul.topnav li {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

ul.topnav li a {
    padding: 14px 26px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

ul.topnav li .drp-down .menu .sub-menu .menu {
    display: none;
    min-width: 160px;
    z-index: 10;   
}

ul.topnav li.icon {
    display: none;
}

ul.topnav:not(.responsive) li:hover:not(.icon) {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #FB8C00;
}

ul.topnav:not(.responsive) li.active:not(.icon) {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #FB8C00;
}

ul.topnav li .drp-down {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    margin-top: 3px;
}

ul.topnav li .drp-down .menu {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
}

ul.topnav li .drp-down .search {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    border: none;
}

ul.topnav li .drp-down .menu input {
    line-height: 24px;
}

ul.topnav li .drp-down .menu a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    min-width: 167px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

ul.topnav li .drp-down a:hover {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

ul.topnav:not(.responsive) li .drp-down .menu .sub-menu:hover > .menu {
    display: inherit;
}

ul.topnav:not(.responsive) li:hover .drp-down {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
}

.ink {
    display: block; position: absolute;
    background: hsl(180, 40%, 80%);
    border-radius: 100%;
    transform: scale(0);
}
/*animation effect*/
.ink.animate {
    animation: ripple 0.7s linear;
}

@keyframes ripple {
    /*scale the element to 250% to safely cover the entire link and fade it out*/
    100% {opacity: 0; transform: scale(2.5);}
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
    ul.topnav li:not(.active) {display: none;}
    ul.topnav li.icon {
        float: right;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    ul.topnav.responsive {
        position: relative;
    }

    ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }

    ul.topnav.responsive li {
        float: none;
        display: inline;
        position: static
    }

    ul.topnav.responsive li a {
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

    ul.topnav.responsive .drop {
        display: inherit;
    }

    ul.topnav {
        margin-right: 26px;
        margin-left: 26px;
    }
}

html { 
    font-family: "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
}

.top {
    background-color: #009688;
    top: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
}

.fancy {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(48, 79, 254, 1)) !important;
    background: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(48, 79, 254, 1)) !important;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(48, 79, 254, 1)) !important;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(48, 79, 254, 1), rgba(0,0,0,0)) !important;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
}

.index {
    min-height: 200px;
    max-height: none;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #E0E0E0 !important;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
}

.index .title {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #FB8C00;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
}

.index .content {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.index .content img {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
    width: 50%;
}

.index .content .centerd {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.index .content h1 {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 23px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #F4511E;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
}

.subindex {
    min-height: 200px;
    max-height: none;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #E0E0E0 !important;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
}

.subindex .content {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.subindex .title {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #C0CA33;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
}

#about {

}

#projects {

}

@viewport {
    zoom: 1.0;
    width: extend-to-zoom; 
}
@-ms-viewport {
    width: extend-to-zoom;
    zoom: 1.0;
}

@media screen and (min-width:680px) {
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
    .menu {
        margin-top: 0px !important;
    }

    .mainindex {
        margin-left: 10px !important;
        margin-right: 10px !important;
        width: calc(100% - 36px) !important;
    }

    .index .content {
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955362/displayinline-block-not-working-on-safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Debugging

If something like this happens to you in the future you need to debug it.

All modern browsers feature in-built Web Inspectors/Developer Tools (and if they're not good enough for you - you can always grab Firebug).

If website looks different in X browsers all you need to do is to inspect the different-looking elements and then see what CSS rules are being applied to them. The differences are almost always related to different rules being applied. If you can't track existing rules in your CSS files they're most likely being added with JavaScript.

I've recorded a quick gif for your case, notice **everything is fine after you remove floats and min-widths from your links** (as previously stated by Imube). You don't actually need floats there, as `inline-block` will work just fine. I'd generally recommend avoiding floats wherever possible.

### Opera vs Safari - tracking your problem using Dev Tools

[image: Opera vs Safari Dev Tools]

Uncompressed: https://gifyu.com/images/debug47afb.gif

### Why it was not working

Looks like Safari <s>interprets</s> ignores `display:inline-block` in comparison other browsers (by the way what is `inline-block` supposed to mean in this case?).

It's really easy to track down using dev tools:

### Learn more

Read more about dev tools for Chrome, Firefox and in Safari.

[see full answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955362/displayinline-block-not-working-on-safari)